# Getting the row with max value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have a df like that:

```
id  state     date
21  Attivato  05/07/2015
21  Cessato   02/22/2015
```

I'd like to have a dataframe with only row with max date in it. How can it be performed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find the most recent date:

```
recent_date = df['date'].max()
```

And then get the dataframe with the recent date:

```
df[df['date'] == recent_date]
```

To get the row with Top n dates (say top 2 dates),

```
top_2 = df['date'].nlargest(2)
df[df['date'].isin(top_2)]
```